# How to create a matrix with four 1's in each row staggered

Tags: r, matrix

How can I easily create this matrix using clever commands:

```
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0 
0 1 0
0 1 0 
0 1 0 
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
unname(model.matrix(~gl(3,4) + 0))

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    1    0
 [7,]    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1
[10,]    0    0    1
[11,]    0    0    1
[12,]    0    0    1
```

Another Option:

```
as.matrix(Matrix::bdiag(rep(list(rep(1,4)),3)))

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    1    0
 [7,]    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1
[10,]    0    0    1
[11,]    0    0    1
[12,]    0    0    1

as.matrix(Matrix::bdiag(replicate(3, numeric(4)+1, FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the shortest and fastest option uses `diag` and modular math:

```r
 diag(3)[0:11 %/% 4 + 1,]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    1    0
 [7,]    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1
[10,]    0    0    1
[11,]    0    0    1
[12,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: I was thinking a similar one of `diag(3)[rep(seq(3),each=4),]`

Comment: I had that initially @thelatemail but thought shaving off 4 characters counted as "cleverer". I'd probably stick to `rep` in real code though.

Answer (score 3):

```
matrix(rep(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1), each = 4),ncol = 3)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    1    0
 [7,]    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1
[10,]    0    0    1
[11,]    0    0    1
[12,]    0    0    1
```